# String compression (Interview prepare)

Tags: c++, string, compression

I need to compress a string. Can make an assumption that each character in the string doesn`t appear more than 255 times. I need return the compressed string and its length.
Last 2 years I worked with C# and forgot C++. I will be glad to hear your comments about code , algorithm and c++ programming practices

```
// StringCompressor.h
class StringCompressor
{
public:
    StringCompressor();
    ~StringCompressor();
    unsigned long Compress(string str, string* strCompressedPtr);
    string DeCompress(string strCompressed);
private:
    string m_StrCompressed;
    static const char c_MaxLen;
};
// StringCompressor.cpp
#include "StringCompressor.h"
const char StringCompressor::c_MaxLen = 255;

StringCompressor::StringCompressor()
{
}


StringCompressor::~StringCompressor()
{
}

unsigned long StringCompressor::Compress(string str, string* strCompressedPtr)
{
    if (str.empty())
    {
        return 0;
    }

    char currentChar = str[0];
    char count = 1;
    for (string::iterator it = str.begin() + 1; it != str.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (*it == currentChar)
        {
            count++;
            if (count == c_MaxLen)
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            m_StrCompressed+=currentChar;
            m_StrCompressed+=count;
            currentChar = *it;
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    m_StrCompressed += currentChar;
    m_StrCompressed += count;
    *strCompressedPtr = m_StrCompressed;
    return m_StrCompressed.length();
}

string StringCompressor::DeCompress(string strCompressed)
{
    string res;
    if (strCompressed.length() % 2 != 0)
    {
        return res;
    }
    for (string::iterator it = strCompressed.begin(); it != strCompressed.end(); it+=2)
    {
        char dup = *(it + 1);
        res += string(dup, *it);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: It seems like this question would be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Use references to pass big arguments to functions. e.g. `unsigned long StringCompressor::Compress(const string &str, string &strCompressed)`

Comment: @Yakov Could you at first say what are you trying to do?! How are you going to compress strings?

Comment: @Yakov I am sure that thsi " Last 2 years I worked with C# and forgot "C++" is a good reason not to go to the interview.:).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow:)it could be simply seen from the code. each char will appear in compressed string followed by the char representing its count

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I didn`t ask you for advise if I should go

Comment: I would make your compression method something like `string  & StringCompressor::Compress(string &str)`, since string has already a method size() to know its lenght. The references  (&) ensure that you don' t end passing around big amount of copied data.

Comment: @Yakov if things can be "simply seen from the code" why do you ask?

Comment: @Yakov The fact itself that they invited you to an interview says that tthere is incompetent personal in this firm..

Comment: @VladfromMoscow-eto ne tvoe delo. offtop.

Comment: @tobi303  It si a code of a beginner.

Comment: @Yakov This requirement  "I need return the compressed string and its length" looks strange because if you return an object of type std::string then the user always can determine its size himself. There is no any need to return the  length. It is encapsulated in std::string. I would define two functional objects for compressiong and decompressing that they could be used in algorithms. However I am sure that who will conduct the interview  is incompetent as I already said.:)

Answer (score 0):

There can be many improvement:

1. Do not return -1 for a `unsigned long` function.
2. consider use `size_t` or `ssize_t` to represent size.
3. Learn `const`
4. m_StrCompressed has bogus state if `Compress` is called repeatedly. Since those member cannot be reused, you may as well make the function static.
5. Compressed stuff generally should not be considered string, but byte buffer. Redesign your interface.
6. Comments! Nobody knows you are doing RLE here.
7. Bonus: Fallback mechanism if your compression yield larger result. e.g. a flag to denote uncompressed buffer, or just return failure.
8. I assume efficiency is not major concern here.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- I'm all for using classes, and perhaps you could do that here in a way that makes more sense. But given the scope of what you are trying to do, this here would be better off as two functions. One for compression, one for decompression. For instance, why are you storing the string in the class as an object and never using it? How does grouping this as a class actually enhance the functionality or make it more reusable?
- You should pass your compressed string return as a reference instead of a pointer.
- It looks like you are trying to count the number of times characters are repeated in a row and save that. For most common strings this will make the size of your compressed string larger than uncompressed as it takes two bytes to store each non-repeated character.
- There are a lot of characters, there are two kinds of bits. If you do this method trying to group repeated bits, you'd be more successful (and that's actually one simple method of lossless compression).
- If you are allowed, just use a library like zlib to do compression of arbitrary data types.